# My echo file is returning the incorrect order for files

Tags: ffmpeg, echo

So I'm using FFmpeg to join a list of .ts files together, to do this I need to create an echo file with all the names of the .ts files in chronological order. The files are all named as numbers, in my case it's within the range 48 and 272.

To create the echo file I am using this command:

```
(for %i in (*.ts) do @echo file '%i') > mylist.txt
```

When I'm running this command in cmd it produces the output, however, it produces it in the wrong order. Rather than doing it based by its name(which are numbers), its sorting it based on an order I'm unaware of.

Here is the output:

```
file '100.ts'
file '101.ts'
file '102.ts'
file '103.ts'
file '104.ts'
file '105.ts'
file '106.ts'
file '107.ts'
file '108.ts'
file '109.ts'
file '110.ts'
file '111.ts'
file '112.ts'
file '113.ts'
file '114.ts'
file '115.ts'
file '116.ts'
file '117.ts'
file '118.ts'
file '119.ts'
file '120.ts'
file '121.ts'
file '122.ts'
file '123.ts'
file '124.ts'
file '125.ts'
file '126.ts'
file '127.ts'
file '128.ts'
file '129.ts'
file '130.ts'
file '131.ts'
file '132.ts'
file '133.ts'
file '134.ts'
file '135.ts'
file '136.ts'
file '137.ts'
file '138.ts'
file '139.ts'
file '140.ts'
file '141.ts'
file '142.ts'
file '143.ts'
file '144.ts'
file '145.ts'
file '146.ts'
file '147.ts'
file '148.ts'
file '149.ts'
file '150.ts'
file '151.ts'
file '152.ts'
file '153.ts'
file '154.ts'
file '155.ts'
file '156.ts'
file '157.ts'
file '158.ts'
file '159.ts'
file '160.ts'
file '161.ts'
file '162.ts'
file '163.ts'
file '164.ts'
file '165.ts'
file '166.ts'
file '167.ts'
file '168.ts'
file '169.ts'
file '170.ts'
file '171.ts'
file '172.ts'
file '173.ts'
file '174.ts'
file '175.ts'
file '176.ts'
file '177.ts'
file '178.ts'
file '179.ts'
file '180.ts'
file '181.ts'
file '182.ts'
file '183.ts'
file '184.ts'
file '185.ts'
file '186.ts'
file '187.ts'
file '188.ts'
file '189.ts'
file '190.ts'
file '191.ts'
file '192.ts'
file '193.ts'
file '194.ts'
file '195.ts'
file '196.ts'
file '197.ts'
file '198.ts'
file '199.ts'
file '200.ts'
file '201.ts'
file '202.ts'
file '203.ts'
file '204.ts'
file '205.ts'
file '206.ts'
file '207.ts'
file '208.ts'
file '209.ts'
file '210.ts'
file '211.ts'
file '212.ts'
file '213.ts'
file '214.ts'
file '215.ts'
file '216.ts'
file '217.ts'
file '218.ts'
file '219.ts'
file '220.ts'
file '221.ts'
file '222.ts'
file '223.ts'
file '224.ts'
file '225.ts'
file '226.ts'
file '227.ts'
file '228.ts'
file '229.ts'
file '230.ts'
file '231.ts'
file '232.ts'
file '233.ts'
file '234.ts'
file '235.ts'
file '236.ts'
file '237.ts'
file '238.ts'
file '239.ts'
file '240.ts'
file '241.ts'
file '242.ts'
file '243.ts'
file '244.ts'
file '245.ts'
file '246.ts'
file '247.ts'
file '248.ts'
file '249.ts'
file '250.ts'
file '251.ts'
file '252.ts'
file '253.ts'
file '254.ts'
file '255.ts'
file '256.ts'
file '257.ts'
file '258.ts'
file '259.ts'
file '260.ts'
file '261.ts'
file '262.ts'
file '263.ts'
file '264.ts'
file '265.ts'
file '266.ts'
file '267.ts'
file '268.ts'
file '269.ts'
file '270.ts'
file '271.ts'
file '272.ts'
file '48.ts'
file '49.ts'
file '50.ts'
file '51.ts'
file '52.ts'
file '53.ts'
file '54.ts'
file '55.ts'
file '56.ts'
file '57.ts'
file '58.ts'
file '59.ts'
file '60.ts'
file '61.ts'
file '62.ts'
file '63.ts'
file '64.ts'
file '65.ts'
file '66.ts'
file '67.ts'
file '68.ts'
file '69.ts'
file '70.ts'
file '71.ts'
file '72.ts'
file '73.ts'
file '74.ts'
file '75.ts'
file '76.ts'
file '77.ts'
file '78.ts'
file '79.ts'
file '80.ts'
file '81.ts'
file '82.ts'
file '83.ts'
file '84.ts'
file '85.ts'
file '86.ts'
file '87.ts'
file '88.ts'
file '89.ts'
file '90.ts'
file '91.ts'
file '92.ts'
file '93.ts'
file '94.ts'
file '95.ts'
file '96.ts'
file '97.ts'
file '98.ts'
file '99.ts'
```

It completely skips the ts files from 48-99 and adds them at the end. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as I've had success using this script before.

Any help is apppreciated

Comment: I've also used this commad: for /r %f in (*.ts) do echo file '%~nxf' >>%~dpf\concat.txt    But still no luck

Comment: Related? [*Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/).

Answer (score 1):

Names are sorted *lexicographically*, not as numbers, i.e. first go names with `1` as the first “letter”, then with `2`, and so on.

Rename your 2-digit files to 3-digit, with *zero at the start*, e. g. `48.ts` to `048.ts`. There are tools for renaming multiple files at once, for example [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) can do it very friendly.

Comment: Nice, I'll check this out and get back to you